# Is there a way to auto-generate hibernate.cfg.xml file in netbeans/eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

Actually i'm learning jpa, so i must learn with examples. 
I found that the manual creation of hibernate is annoying, 
every time i have to copy and paste the structure of that file 
So i was thinking is there any solution to auto-generate the " hibernate.cfg.xml " file automatically via netbeans/eclipse ?

Comment: you dont need a hibernate.cfg.xml file to use JPA, persistence.xml should be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Netbeans** automatically generates a `hibernate.cfg.xml` if you create a Web Application Project that uses Hibernate (see the Netbeans documentation on [Using Hibernate in a Web Application](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html)). According to [this guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html#03a), you can also create the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file using *New* → *Other* and then selecting *Hibernate Configuration Wizard* in the *Hibernate* group.
- In **Eclipse**, the Hibernate Tools plugin provides a wizard to create the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file (see the [JBoss Hibernate Tools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#hib_config_file)).

**Edit:** *Add information about the file wizard in Netbeans.*

Comment: Thanks Bro, but is there any solution to generate " hibernate.cfg.xml " when i create Java Application (not Web Application ) ?

Comment: I don’t have a Netbeans installation available, but according to the documentation, it should work as described in [this guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html#03a).